# Flutter Web error with date picker height

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Im current using flutter web 1.12.14

Im trying to use a datepicker and its work good, but the dialog is showing in all screen, as this way

[image]

Is there any way to limit the height of the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the size of the date pickers we can use `builder` parameter:

```dart
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.date_range),
        onPressed: () async {
          final choice = await showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              firstDate: DateTime(2010),
              lastDate: DateTime(2030),
              initialDate: DateTime.now(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                return Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                  width: 400.0,
                  height: 500.0,
                  child: child,
                ));
              });
          print(choice);
        },
      )
```

[image]